# formatWithString: Cocos2d-x passing in a CCString

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Maybe i'm going about this wrong, and if i am please tell me because i just dont know any better.

But i am trying to pass in a CCString into the following format, and not having any luck. Could someone please tell me what the parameter for strings would be in C++ when passing them into another string?

Code:

```
CCString tilt = "";

        if (recalculatedFrames >= 4 && (numberOfTimesRun > 0 && numberOfTimesRun < recalculatedFrames - 1)) {
            tilt = "TR_";
        }

        initalTurnAnimationFrames->addObject(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(CCString::stringWithFormat("%s%d.png", tilt, i)));
```

Also is it fine to make a blank string like i am doing with tilt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
CCString::stringWithFormat("%s%d.png", tilt.getCString(), i)
```

Comment: hmmm, i get the error `Cannot initalize a parameter of the type 'const char *' with an rvalue of type 'cocos2d::CCString, *'`

Comment: Try `(char*)(CCString::stringWithFormat("%s%d.png", tilt.getCString(), i));`

Comment: this is deprecated function now

Comment: so use initWithFormat instead. is it a problem?

Comment: It is now CCString::createWithFormat, so:-  CCString *cs = CCString::createWithFormat("%s%i", "Hello", 21 );

Answer (score 4):

I think `tilt` should be class of `string`
And the `CCString` part should be
`CCString::createWithFormat("%s%d.png", tilt.c_str(), i);`